# how to add every package to Package-Blacklist of Unattended-Upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I'm trying to figure out how to add every my installed packages to `Package-Blacklist` of `Unattended-Upgrade`, Ubuntu.

I already tried `*`, but it doesn't work. just occurred an error.

```
 Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    "*";
};
```

I just want to make my server to do only auto security upgrades itself.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself.

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
"";
```

};

The blank (`""`) would work just like `*`.